# pull SQL results for search criteria conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, search

Notice the 2 queries below.  The 1st one does a union on 4 queries.  I'm trying to write #2 for search conditions based on the 3 SQL variables prefixed with an "@".  So rather than doing a union, we have to take all 3 parameters into consideration for the search.  And if any parameter/variable is '' (or NULL), just ignore that condition, but still perform the search.  But all fields have to combine with each other for a single row/record in the search results.

How do I re-write QUERY #2 so that it pulls results based on the search conditions (@companyName, @primaryPhone and @postalCode)?  I think each section in the where clause has to have some OR condition (so it doesn't skip the row for a ''/NULL search condition), but I'm curious how this is typically done.  The @primaryPhone part of the where clause is a little trickier because it looks at both phone and fax.

**QUERY #1**

```
SELECT tempTable.optionValue, tempTable.optionText FROM (   

    SELECT 
        address.addressid AS 'optionValue', 
        address.name AS 'optionText'
    FROM 
        dbo.address 
    WHERE 
        addressid=1

    UNION

    -- Company Name internal partial match
    SELECT 
        address.addressid AS 'optionValue', 
        ('[' + CAST(address.addressid AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '] ' + ISNULL(address.name,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(address1,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(city,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(statecode,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(countrycode,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(postalcode,'')) AS 'optionText'
    FROM 
        dbo.[address]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.contact_address ON dbo.address.addressid = dbo.contact_address.addressid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clientcontact ON dbo.contact_address.contactid = dbo.clientcontact.contactid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.client ON dbo.clientcontact.clientid = dbo.client.clientid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.contact ON dbo.contact_address.contactid = dbo.contact.contactid
    WHERE 
        client.name IS NOT NULL 
        AND client.name != ''
        AND @companyName != ''
        AND @companyName IS NOT NULL
        AND client.name LIKE '%' + @companyName + '%' 
        AND clientcontact.contacttypeid = 3 --primary contacts only

    UNION

    -- Primary Phone/Fax internal partial match     
    SELECT 
        address.addressid AS 'optionValue', 
        ('[' + CAST(address.addressid AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '] ' + ISNULL(address.name,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(address1,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(city,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(statecode,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(countrycode,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(postalcode,'')) AS 'optionText'
    FROM 
        dbo.[contact]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clientcontact ON dbo.contact.contactid = dbo.clientcontact.contactid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.contact_address ON dbo.contact.contactid = dbo.contact_address.contactid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.address ON dbo.contact_address.addressid = dbo.address.addressid
    WHERE 
        (
            contact.dayphone IS NOT NULL 
            AND contact.dayphone != ''
            AND @primaryPhone != ''
            AND @primaryPhone IS NOT NULL
            AND contact.dayphone LIKE '%' + @primaryPhone + '%'
        )
        OR 
        (
            contact.fax IS NOT NULL 
            AND contact.fax != ''
            AND @primaryPhone != ''
            AND @primaryPhone IS NOT NULL
            AND contact.fax LIKE '%' + @primaryPhone + '%' 
        )
        AND clientcontact.contacttypeid = 3 --primary contacts only

    UNION

    SELECT 
        address.addressid AS 'optionValue', 
        ('[' + CAST(address.addressid AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '] ' + ISNULL(address.name,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(address1,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(city,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(statecode,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(countrycode,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(postalcode,'')) AS 'optionText'
    FROM 
        dbo.[contact]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clientcontact ON dbo.contact.contactid = dbo.clientcontact.contactid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.contact_address ON dbo.contact.contactid = dbo.contact_address.contactid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.address ON dbo.contact_address.addressid = dbo.address.addressid
    WHERE 
        @postalCode != ''
        AND @postalCode IS NOT NULL
        AND address.postalcode LIKE @postalCode + '%'
        AND clientcontact.contacttypeid = 3 --primary contacts only

) AS tempTable
```

**QUERY #2 (SEARCH)**

```
SELECT tempTable.optionValue, tempTable.optionText FROM (   

    SELECT 
        address.addressid AS 'optionValue', 
        address.name AS 'optionText'
    FROM 
        dbo.address 
    WHERE 
        addressid=1

    UNION

    SELECT 
        address.addressid AS 'optionValue', 
        ('[' + CAST(address.addressid AS NVARCHAR(10)) + '] ' + ISNULL(address.name,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(address1,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(city,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(statecode,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(countrycode,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(postalcode,'')) AS 'optionText'
    FROM 
        dbo.[address]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.contact_address ON dbo.address.addressid = dbo.contact_address.addressid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.clientcontact ON dbo.contact_address.contactid = dbo.clientcontact.contactid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.client ON dbo.clientcontact.clientid = dbo.client.clientid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.contact ON dbo.contact_address.contactid = dbo.contact.contactid
    WHERE 
        (
            client.name IS NOT NULL 
            AND client.name != ''
            AND @companyName != ''
            AND @companyName IS NOT NULL
            AND client.name LIKE '%' + @companyName + '%' 
        )
        AND 
        (
            (
                contact.dayphone IS NOT NULL 
                AND contact.dayphone != ''
                AND @primaryPhone != ''
                AND @primaryPhone IS NOT NULL
                AND contact.dayphone LIKE '%' + @primaryPhone + '%'
            )
            OR 
            (
                contact.fax IS NOT NULL 
                AND contact.fax != ''
                AND @primaryPhone != ''
                AND @primaryPhone IS NOT NULL
                AND contact.fax LIKE '%' + @primaryPhone + '%' 
            )
        )
        AND
        (
            @postalCode != ''
            AND @postalCode IS NOT NULL
            AND address.postalcode LIKE @postalCode + '%'
        )                       
        AND clientcontact.contacttypeid = 3 --primary contacts only

) AS tempTable
```

Comment: If a field is NULL, due to LEFT JOINs, should that condition be ignored?  (Or reworded, if the field is NULL, it is never excluded.)

Comment: yes, ignore that condition if ''/NULL, but don't exclude the row if it's ''/NULL

Comment: I meant to write "yes, ignore that SEARCH condition if '' (or NULL), but don't exclude the row if the SEARCH condition '' (or NULL)" ... you were asking about the field in the records in the database, not the search conditions.. in that case, I want to exclude those records if the record/row field is '' (or NULL) ... so I don't want all those OR conditions in your amended answer @Dems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** New Rules

```
                     |  Field = '' or NULL  |  Field != '' or NULL
---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------
Param  = '' or NULL  |    Include Record    |    Include Record
---------------------+----------------------+-----------------------
Param != '' or NULL  |    Exclude Record    |   Include if Match
```

```
WHERE 
    (
           @companyName = ''
        OR @companyName IS NULL
        OR client.name LIKE '%' + @companyName + '%' 
    )
    AND 
    (
        (
               @primaryPhone = ''
            OR @primaryPhone IS NULL
            OR contact.dayphone LIKE '%' + @primaryPhone + '%'
        )
        OR 
        (
               @primaryPhone = ''
            OR @primaryPhone IS NULL
            OR contact.fax LIKE '%' + @primaryPhone + '%' 
        )
    )
    AND
    (
           @postalCode = ''
        OR @postalCode IS NULL
        OR address.postalcode LIKE @postalCode + '%'
    )                       
    AND clientcontact.contacttypeid = 3 --primary contacts only
```

Comment: the 1st (@companyName) and 2nd (@primaryPhone) conditions are partial internal matches.. the 3rd (@postalCode) is a starts-with (that's why I have the % only at the end of the LIKE condition)

Comment: @MacGyver - I assumed you could make those kind of modifications yourself :)

Comment: see my comment under question

Comment: "1. If a field is NULL or '', do not exclude it" ... should be written, "1. If a field is NULL or '', exclude it"

Comment: thanks.. In my first query, I was checking if the database fields were != '' and NOT NULL ... that's what confused me when I re-wrote it. +1

Comment: @MacGyver - Also, you had AND where you needed OR.

Answer (score 0):

```
@postalCode != ''
            AND @postalCode IS NOT NULL
            AND address.postalcode LIKE @postalCode + '%'
```

could be written as

```
AND address.postalcode LIKE IsNull(@postalCode, '') + '%'
```

no need for testing that you have a variable at all, sql will ignore it in the execution when = '%'

a mass of ORs in my experience will really slow down the query (but look at the exe plan anyway). this is a heck of a lot easier on the eye also imo.

Comment: `sql will ignore it in the execution when = '%'` - This is not always true.  If this is for a Stored Procedure or Parameterised Query, the execution ***plan*** will have already been formed to cater for comparing ALL of the parameters.  This includes which index and sorting is necessary, regardless of the value in the parameter.  The caution over speed is warranted though.  But being that some or many comparisons could be `LIKE '%xxx%'` this will be a table scan any way.